# Why does chat only show up on the sidebar in meta, but not on the main site?

Tags: support, bug, design, chat

I don't see the

> XXXXX People Chatting
>   Mos Eisley
>   Agent of Nothing

on the main site, yet it shows up on meta. Why is this?

**EDIT:** I see it sometimes. Other times... it's gone.

Comment: Related from main meta: [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127282/show-the-chat-box-in-the-sidebar-for-public-beta-sites?rq=1) (especially), [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257677/how-are-the-chatrooms-shown-in-the-sidebar-selected), [three](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240186/faq-sidebar-for-per-site-metas).

Comment: I see it on the main site myself, if that helps narrow it down between site-wde or user-wide

Comment: It does show up sometimes on main site: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bkcrJ.png This is definitely [meta-tag:status-bydesign], though I'm not sure about the *why*.